# Move git project from BitBucket to AWS CodeCommit

Tags: git, bitbucket, aws-codecommit

Is there a way I can move a project that is on BitBucket to AWS CodeCommit and keep all the commit history?

Comment: You can push any git repo to any git host and it will keep the history of the repo.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the code on your local machine?

Comment: @declan yes and full access to the repository

Comment: Does the answer below work for you? Looks like you don't have enough rep to comment directly on the answer, but you can leave a comment here if there's anything about that that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @declan yes it is working , thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you push your code to AWS, it should have the full commit history. First make the repository in the AWS console, then

```
# On your local machine
cd path/to/git/repo
git remote add aws git@git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/your-repo-name

git push -u aws master
```

When you push a branch to another repository, the full commit history goes along with it. Anyone who checks the code out of the AWS repository will be able to see all commits.